# In this sentence, what does "starting to forget" mean?

Tags: meaning

'I'm starting to forget their voices. I'm not trying to, but they keep fading away.'

What does "starting" mean? Does this mean the person already forgot, and every time she tries to remember, it fades away? Does this mean she hasn't completely forgotten (before they fade away completely, she still remembers a little)? Does it mean she has completely forgotten?

What about

'I'm really starting to hate you.'?

Comment: It uses *starting* in the usual way: just begun and certainly not completed.

Answer (score 1):

I take "starting to forget" as meaning something like "occasionally unable to remember".

Forgetting doesn't happen all at once.  Rather,  the number of times to try to remember, and can't, goes up with time.  At other times, the memory comes back to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the voices, “starting to forget” would generally mean that the clarity of the memories is no longer as strong as it once had been, but they are still memories.

In the case of “starting to hate you”. That would generally mean “something is happened that made me hate you” but would hint that, “given some past, positive, experience i habe had with you, perhaps that could be mitigated.”